# Fourier switching in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})\setminus S(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, schwartz-space

Similar to the question listed here: [Fourier switching in $L^2(R)/S(R)$ in the integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290680/fourier-switching-in-l2r-sr-in-the-integral/2290727#2290727)

If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}), g \in S(\mathbb{R})$, (where $S(\mathbb{R})$ is the Schwartz space) then how can I show that, integrating over $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
     \int \hat{f}(\xi) \, g(\xi) \, d\xi = \int f(\xi) \, \hat{g}(\xi) \, d\xi
$$

I know that the fourier switching works for $f,g \in S(\mathbb{R})$. So I wanted to use the continuity of the fourier transformation and the schwartz space's density to extend to $L^1$, but the fourier transformation does not necessarily map to $L^1$. What is the best way to prove this?

Comment: Use Fubini. $\, \, \, $

Comment: @CameronWilliams is that helpful once you know that fourier switching works for $f,g\in S(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: If they are both in $L^1$, then you don't even need to use an approximating sequence as in the other post. In that case $f(x) g(\xi)e^{-i\xi x}$ is absolutely integrable on the product space $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ so  you can just apply Fubini directly to the $L^1$ functions. When they are in $L^2$, we don't know that $f(x) g(\xi)e^{-i\xi x}$ is absolutely integrable so we need to approximate them with Schwartz functions.

Comment: That makes sense! How do we know that $f(x)g(\xi)\exp(-i\xi x)$ is absolutely integrable? Why does it hold that these are not ncessarily absolutely integrable in the $L^2$ case?

Comment: @communistrob define $H(x,\xi) = |f(x) g(\xi) \exp(-i\xi x)|$, then by Tonneli we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} H \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}\xi = \int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x \cdot \int_\mathbb{R} |g(\xi)|\mathrm{d}x<\infty$